# Do I need a transit visa in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit, filipino-citizens

I am from the Philippines and going to travel to Sweden next month. My flights are:

- Cebu (CEB)-Singapore (SIN) with AirAsia
- Singapore (SIN)-London (LGW) with Norwegian Air UK
- London (LGW)-Göteborg (GOT) with Norwegian

Every flight is with a different airline, so I need to get my baggage and check them in again. My layover time is 3 hours and 10 minutes in Singapore and in London 3 hours and 40 minutes. I will stay only inside the airport.

I hold a residence permit, which is valid for two years and I have a complete confirmed plane ticket (all flights). But I am confused whether I need to get a transit visa, since I will check in every airport, even if it's a connecting flight, especially at Gatwick Airport in London.

Just in case, do I need to have a transit visa? Can I get it at the airport upon arrival?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that if your booking is in separate tickets, you risk losing your flight and your money. E.g. if CEB-SIN is 3 hours late, you'll miss SIN-LGW and neither airline will refund you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Norwegian connects to Norwegian at Gatwick. I've personallly done it between their local European routes and intercontinental. Baggage checked through, no need to pass immigration.

Comment: Norwegian has subsidiaries for legal reasons, but as @HenningMakholm says, they will through-check your luggage from SIN to GOT. At least, they through-check intra-Europe connecting to transatlantic, which also involves two separate subsidiaries.

Answer (score 2):

> Every flight is with a different airline, so I need to get my baggage and check them in again. My layover time is 3 hours and 10 minutes in Singapore and in London 3 hours and 40 minutes. I will stay only inside the airport.

No. If you have to pick up your luggage and check it in again, you will have to enter the country. So for the immigration services, whether you are going no further than the departure hall, or all the way to downtown, it is the same, you're entering the country. In the case of Singapore, AirAsia is in T1, and Norwegian Air will be in T4. No airside connection. You'll have to exit T1 and take transportation to T4. Fortunately, you don't need a visa for Singapore. So that part's taken care of.

You don't mention which country your residence permit is for. If it is for Sweden it seems like this is listed among the [Visitor in Transit visa exemption documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_Kingdom#Transit). So in which case you wouldn't need a transit visa there either.

Comment: I automatically assumed it's a Swedish Permit.

Comment: yes, my residence permit is for Sweden

Comment: yes, its s residence permit to sweden.

Answer (score 1):

UK visas are ***never*** issued on arrival.

But as per the [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/transit/somewhere_else/yes) website, you can enter the UK by presenting your passport, Swedish residence permit card and connecting ticket to Gothenburg.

So no, you do **not** need a visa